# How does Islam prove the existence of the life of the world to come?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, death, judgements, barzakh

I have a question:

- What is the basis for the Islam belief in the World to Come?

i asked same question here:

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23376/2188

Comment: Please split this into three questions - while they are related, they are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is obvious scriptural basis. The Quran asserts final judgement repeatedly and in no uncertain terms. It would be hard to list them all! (Maybe someone has made such a list?)

Perhaps chapter 78 (al-nabaa) or 99 (al-zilzal) will be good examples.